# How to know where a R package has been installed

Tags: r, package

Good moorning

I would like to know if there is a way to find where a package is installed.

Actually, I am currently documenting a package. In my package, I have a function called "read.myfile" which reads a specific kind of file (roughly like read.table). 
I have an instance of this kind of file named "myfile.txt" in my package's folder. On my documentation, I want to run an executable example of this function. 
That's why I need the path, where the user has installed the package. So with this path, I can obtain the path of the file "myfile.txt" and use the function "read.myfile" in the .Rd help file, which gives help about the function "read.myfile".
Thus my example will be executable wherever the user has installed the package.

I hope my message was clear.
I don't know if it's possible to do that, but if anyone knows, thanks for helping me.

Comment: You can use `path.package()` or `system.file()`

Comment: Or `.libPaths()` - first element is the default install location if no library has been specified when `install.package` was used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the function `system.file`.

For example:

```
system.file(package="ggplot2")
[1] "C:/Users/Andrie/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/ggplot2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `installed.packages` and subset to get the only the location of the library in which it is installed:

```
installed.packages()["tools","LibPath"]
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library"
```

Comment: Yes, the result of the command is actually very rich. Thanks, now I do know this function.